# How to colour-code the objects in an image using MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, label, processing

I have an image: [image] to which I have performed segmentation to receive a binary image. I'd like to label each of the objects in the image with different colours. I have the following code so far:

```
img = imread('lab5a.tif');
BW = imbinarize(img,graythresh(img));
figure; imshowpair(img,BW,'montage')
title ('Opening Operation on Image');
se = strel ('disk', 3);
rem = imclose(BW,se);
figure; imshow (rem, []);
title ('Removed Undesired Features');
CC = bwconncomp(rem);
L = labelmatrix(CC);
RGB = label2rgb(L, spring, 'c', 'shuffle');
figure; imshow(RGB, []);
```

The output is this image: [image: Output] which is not what I want. It colours the background and the objects are white. I would just like the objects to be of different colours.

Any form of help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you inspected the variables you've created? How big are `CC` and `L`? It would be helpful to describe any debugging you've done, but my guess is it's treating the "objects" as "background".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the background and foreground of the image are reversed from what you think it should be. The default for the matlab commands is to assume that the higher-value pixels (white) are the foreground or items of interest, while the lower-value pixels (black) are the background. So when you run your example code, the object `CC` contains only 1 object (the "background" that is blue in your image):

```
CC = 

  struct with fields:

    Connectivity: 8
       ImageSize: [256 256]
      NumObjects: 1
    PixelIdxList: {[43341×1 double]}
```

Any easy way to fix this is simply to invert your cleaned up image with the [`imcomplement`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcomplement.html) command. Add this line to your code:

```
% invert the image so that the background is black
rem = imcomplement(rem);
```

Now the `CC` struct contains 62 objects identified:

```
CC = 

  struct with fields:

    Connectivity: 8
       ImageSize: [256 256]
      NumObjects: 62
    PixelIdxList: {1×62 cell}
```

And you will get this image:

[image: Colored Items]

If you want to change the colors used for the items, look at the `colormap` property of the `label2rgb` command.